# what is the correct way to dockerize express gatsby application?

Tags: typescript, express, dockerfile, gatsby

PROBLEM:
I have a express-gatsby app that I need to build and deploy using github actions, from what I understood, I will need to containerize my app in order to push it to Heroku. For that, I have created a Dockerfile but to build an image I need to install npm packages for my express and gatsby app and then do a build.

When I run docker build it gets stuck at npm run install. Any help on this will be appreciated thanks.

[screenshot for docker build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDWPC.jpg)

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "install": "npm install && cd /client && install",
    "build": "cd client/ && npm run build && cd .. && node ./util/build.js",
    "lint": "tslint --project \"tsconfig.json\"",
    "start": "node -r module-alias/register ./dist",
    "start:dev": "nodemon --config nodemon.json",
    "test": "nodemon --config nodemon.test.json"
  },
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli

COPY / ./

RUN npm run install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8081

ENV NODE_ENV=production

ENV PORT=8081

RUN ls

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you want to install npm packages inside client:

```
"install": "npm install && cd /client && npm install"
```

Missing `npm` in there...

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, spotted the error later and was able to build the image but the process takes an awful lot of time, do you think my dockerfile is missing something, or is there a better way to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: @TechBasics There are a few things you could do to speed things up. 1) Keep in mind that, by default, whenever you run `docker build [...]` the process is starting from scratch — this can be great for reproducibility, but pretty awful for performance. A common practice in CI environments is to cache resources that are expensive to fetch or build, and that rarely change between builds, like `node_modules`. How you implement this will depend on your build environment, but CircleCI has an excellent overview of the general principle: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/

Comment: @TechBasics 2) A related best-practice leverages the copy-on-write design of the Docker engine, also with to avoid redundant execution between builds. In your example, by running `COPY / ./` you're going to invalidate the build cache for every subsequent layer whenever you change **any file** in your project. Instead, it's common to do something like `COPY package.json package-lock.json ./`, then `RUN npm install`, and *then* copy everything else over: `COPY . ./`. With this approach, you'll find `npm install` is only run if your dependencies change, which can significantly speed things up.

Comment: @TechBasics Hope this helps! Crafting Dockerfiles can be more art than science. [This article](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) lays out some great best-practices. Oh, one last thing: you'll end up with a WAY smaller image if you use a multi-stage build and copy the contents of the `public` folder into a `nginx` alpine image or similar. No reason to include all those node modules just to serve a static site. You can see an example of how to do this in one of my repos: https://github.com/jessestuart/jesses.io/blob/master/Dockerfile